# XCode 4 - libsqlite3.dylib: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to compile a iOS application that uses SQlite in Xcode 4 (for Snow Leopard) and I am getting the following error -

```
error: /Apps/Cocktails/libsqlite3.dylib: No such file or directory
```

I copied the file libsqlite3.dylib into the Xcode project but the error won't go away. How do I resolve the error ?

**EDIT** - Here is the complete error log

```
CpResource libsqlite3.0.dylib /Users/ashishagarwal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cocktails-gzqdmwrvzqciekgjzxnriugcxwwm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Cocktails.app/libsqlite3.0.dylib
cd /Apps/Cocktails
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Apps/Cocktails/libsqlite3.0.dylib /Users/ashishagarwal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cocktails-gzqdmwrvzqciekgjzxnriugcxwwm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Cocktails.app

error: /Apps/Cocktails/libsqlite3.dylib: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Think about it - file is not there. How do you solve it? Stop looking for it in there, or put it there so it can be found.

Comment: I added the file there. Same error, which is why I posted here

Comment: Did you go to Projects -> Build Phases -> Link Binary WIth Libraries - >
Click + and add the libsqlite3.dylib
Clean and run the program.

Comment: Yes, I have added the libsqlite3.0.dylib. If I add the libsqlite3.dylib, it gives 6 errors - everytime I try to open, close, step, etc through the database: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

Comment: Go to Project -> Build Settings -> Architectures give armv6 and armv7 and check it..  Hope this would solve your problem..

Comment: If it works then I will post it as answer..

Comment: At the moment this is what I have 
Architectures - Standard (armv7)
and for Valid architectures - armv6 armv7

Comment: I just wanted to add that I am not creating the database during the code. I created a .sqlite db and populated that with values using Firefox sqlite addon. I am just trying to read the data in the app

Comment: Also, if I remove the sqlite statements, it compiles just fine for some reason. So can I assume that the build settings are also fine ?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply.  For some reason I did not receive your update.  Yes your build settings are fine..I have not tried this scenario i.e creating a DB using FireFox and try to read the data from it.  Usually we create the database from our application and read it.  It will work just fine..

Comment: Have you created datamodel in your application?  Can you put some code on how you try to read the data....

Comment: you have to place these two files libsqlite3.0.dylib and libsqlite3.dylib, it is running on my case

Answer (score 5):

It looks your library is missing libsqlite3.dylib and 
libsqlite3.0.dylib, so copy these files from any other computer and place these files in your computer.

#### Procedure:

**1:**Open xcode on the computer where these files exists, add libsqlite3.0.dylib in your project from link binary with libraries.
**2:** Right click on the libsqlite3.0.dylib and show in finder.
**3:** Copy two files libsqlite3.0.dylib and libsqlite3.dylib and place on the same location on other computer where these files are missing.

Here you go, I had the same problem and solved in this way.